# List of n-tuples in c++

Tags: c++, math, permutation

What is the way to create a list of n-tuples in C++? I would like to generate, given an array of numbers, all the possible n‐tuples of elements from that array:

In Mathematica this is done with: for instance

```
Tuples[{0, 1, 2}, 3]
```

generates:

```
0,0,0
0,0,1
0,0,2
0,1,0
0,1,1
0,1,2
0,2,0
0,2,1
0,2,2
1,0,0
...
2,2,2
```

In Python is done via (see [How to create N-tuples in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21208767/how-to-create-n-tuples-in-python))

```
list(product(range(0, 2), repeat=3))
```

However I cannot figure out how to do it in C++. I would like to have an array [0,1,...,num] and generate the n-tuples of an assigned length.

Perhaps in C++ one could possibly use std::next_permutation or some nested for?

Comment: Do you really need a tuple?  Looks like a 2d vector would work for you.

Comment: just an idea: maybe you can use a recursive function to write it yourself?

Comment: A 2d vector would be perfect! However my question is about how to generate the above sequence, possibly in the most efficient way. A recursive function is exactly what I want to do...but I cannot figure out how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume your vector of numbers is unique.

Do you notice how the tuples appear a lot like incrementing numbers? We can make use of that fact to do this.

First, realize that the set we are pulling tuple elements from basically forms the "digits" in our "number system". So we know we will then have `digits^tupleSize` tuples.

We then just increment a counter and pull the "digits" off from the counter.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>

// Not strictly necessary. You can find other ways to end the loop
uint32_t ipow(uint32_t base, uint32_t exp)
{
    uint32_t result = 1;
    while (exp)
    {
        if (exp & 1)
            result *= base;
        exp >>= 1;
        base *= base;
    }

    return result;
}

std::vector<std::vector<uint32_t>> tuples(const std::vector<uint32_t> &set, uint32_t tupleSize)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<uint32_t>> result;

    uint32_t maxValue = ipow(set.size(), tupleSize);

    for (uint32_t counter = 0; counter < maxValue; counter++) {
        std::vector<uint32_t> tuple(tupleSize);

        uint32_t currentValue = counter;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < tupleSize; i++) {
            uint32_t digit = currentValue % set.size();
            tuple[tupleSize - i - 1] = set[digit];
            currentValue /= set.size();
        }

        result.push_back(tuple);
    }

    return result;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ddc83ac4b882fcff)